# SugarCRM REST API Session expires frequently

Tags: rest, sugarcrm

I use REST API in JavaScript. When I request REST API multiple times, it returns(response) *invalid session id*, but I am providing a valid session id, because I have pulled data with this session id.
Anyone came across this issue?

```js
function sugarLogin(url, user, password) {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = {
    user_auth: {
        user_name: user,
        password: password
    },
    name_value_list: [{
        name: 'notifyonsave',
        value: 'true'
    }]
};
var json = $.toJSON(params);
var crm_api = url;
request.open("POST", crm_api, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        var response = request.responseText;
        var response_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

        if (response_obj) {
            if (response_obj.name && response_obj.name == "Invalid Login") {
                //invalid login
                ProcessingFlag = 3;
            } else {
                session_id = response_obj.id;
                ProcessingFlag = 1;
            }
        }
    } else if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 404) {
        ProcessingFlag = 2;
    }
}
request.send("method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data=" + json);}
```

I have used above code to `login` and set `session_id` (global scope)
and then using this session id I am calling `search_by_module` function of REST API.
It is working fine but if made multiple requests frequently then it says invalid session id.

Although I have tried to call `login` function again before making `search_by_module` call.
Main issue is when I tried calling other REST function after response returned from `search_by_module` and rendered HTML, it says me invalid session. I can't figure out why session expires immediately while we know that on server session expires after 24 minutes (server where our sugar instance hosted)

Comment: i have updated my question and added code for login and i using search_by_module same as this but rest_data and method to call is different.

Answer (score 2):

I bet you're getting this because of item number 3 :

1/ Defined an error callback that checks for that particular response -invalid login- and calls the login function. Reading your code, I guess this is `ProcessingFlag = 3;` job.

2/ make sure the login function updates the session_id correctly and globally so that future function calls will get the correct value.

3/ make sure you're passing that new session_id to all your subsequent calls as `FIRST` parameter in all you rest_data. I got caught on this and lost many hours only to find out that SugarCRM `DOESN'T` support named parameters in its rest_data (is it poorely implemented function-arguments-wise ?) This is because I was adding session_id as last parameter and all of my REST calls were returning invalid ID.

Comment: Already i am doing all as you said, but i found my problem, it is due to change in ip(dynamic ip changes frequently ). and sugar expire session due to significant change in ip.
thanks all for your response.